# Performing character count of a pdf file in javascript console?

Tags: javascript, pdf, document

I want to do a character count of my pdf file in pdf x-change editor using a Javascript console so Bascially I need a code in Javascript to count the characters of a document.

Currently, I am able to count the words using this code.

```
`/* Count the number of words in the document */
var cnt = 0;
for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) cnt += getPageNumWords(p);
app.alert("There are " + cnt + " words in this file.");`
```

Now I want to count the characters.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What did you tried, were are you stuck? What is the `getPageNumWords` method?

Comment: This gets all the word count for the document. Checked it with MS word too so this one is working fine but now I need to count the characters of my document. How to do that using javascript?

Comment: If you have all words, you can count characteres by yourself with that?

Comment: There are 50765 words so manually doing that will take time, I need a short solution to count characters of these words?

Answer (score 1):

To count the characters in a PDF document using JavaScript in PDF-XChange Editor, you can modify your existing code slightly to loop through the pages, extract the text content of each page, and then count the characters. Here's a modified version of your code to count characters:

```js
/* Count number of characters in document */
var charCount = 0;

for (var pageNum = 0; pageNum < this.numPages; pageNum++) {
    var page = this.getPageNumWords(pageNum);
    for (var wordNum = 0; wordNum < page.length; wordNum++) {
        var word = page[wordNum];
        charCount += word.length;
    }
}

app.alert("There are " + charCount + " characters in this file.");
```

This code will loop through each page, extract the words, and count the characters in each word, summing up the character count for the entire document. It will then display the total character count in an alert dialog.

Comment: ALot of waiting time and the code is not responding. Tried it multiple times :(